# Force chrome to crash on timeout instead of prompt for wait / kill?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I have the following code on a page:

```
while(true);
```

The page will hang, but not crash. After 30 seconds (I know this is changeable) or so it will ask if I want to wait or kill it.

Is there a way to just kill it and not ask?

I wrote an extension for chrome (for a kiosk) that will auto-reload a killed page (with the ah snap sign), So I would rather not have the dialog to come up on the computer as users get confused, and it looks bad. Id rather set it so that if the system is unresponsive for 10 seconds, it just kills the page, so it can auto reload.

Comment: You've previously asked how to detect the responsiveness of a page. Can't you just use [`chrome.tabs.remove`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove) to close the tab? (and use [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) to create a tab).

Comment: Rob W, I figure it wouldn't work because I needed it to stay full screen. But this worked perfectly.

Comment: Order matters though: If you close the tab before opening another one, the window will close if the tab was the last tab.

Comment: @Rob W, so create the new tab in the same index, before closing the old one

Comment: That is exactly what I did. `chrome.tabs.create({url: tab.url});
chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);`